# Xamarin.iOS not displaying buttons correctly in Alert

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, alert

[image]

I am not getting my OK Button on Alert.Is this not the code to show an Ok button Alert?

What do i need to change?

```
    public void Alert (List<string> listToAlert, string heading)
            {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder ();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listToAlert.Count; i++) {
                            stringBuilder.Append (listToAlert [i]);
                            stringBuilder.Append ("\r\n");
                    }
                    UIButton okayButton = new UIButton();
                    var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create (heading, stringBuilder.ToString (), UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                    okayButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {    
                            //Add Action
                            okAlertController.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));
                    };
                    _rootVC.PresentViewController (okAlertController, true, null);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution - The above solution by @Ricardo Romo does not compile.
At issue most likely is an assumption around the class the contained type. PresentViewController assumes that the calling class is a ViewController. In my case and many cases, and mine, this is not always true. I am calling from appdelegate.
[image]

```
public class AlertViewController
    {
            #region Static Methods
            public static UIAlertController PresentOKAlert (string title, string description, UIViewController controller)
            {
                    // No, inform the user that they must create a home first
                    UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create (title, description, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                    // Configure the alert
                    alert.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => { }));

                    // Display the alert
                    controller.PresentViewController (alert, true, null);

                    // Return created controller
                    return alert;
            }
            public static UIAlertController PresentOKCancelAlert (string title, string description, UIViewController controller, AlertOKCancelDelegate action)
            {
                    // No, inform the user that they must create a home first
                    UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create (title, description, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                    // Add cancel button
                    alert.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, (actionCancel) => {
                            // Any action?
                            if (action != null) {
                                    action (false);
                            }
                    }));

                    // Add ok button
                    alert.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (actionOK) => {
                            // Any action?
                            if (action != null) {
                                    action (true);
                            }
                    }));

                    // Display the alert
                    controller.PresentViewController (alert, true, null);

                    // Return created controller
                    return alert;
            }
            public static UIAlertController PresentTextInputAlert (string title, string description, string placeholder, string text, UIViewController controller, AlertTextInputDelegate action)
            {
                    // No, inform the user that they must create a home first
                    UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create (title, description, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                    UITextField field = null;

                    // Add and configure text field
                    alert.AddTextField ((textField) => {
                            // Save the field
                            field = textField;

                            // Initialize field
                            field.Placeholder = placeholder;
                            field.Text = text;
                            field.AutocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No;
                            field.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default;
                            field.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;
                            field.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;

                    });

                    // Add cancel button
                    alert.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, (actionCancel) => {
                            // Any action?
                            if (action != null) {
                                    action (false, "");
                            }
                    }));

                    // Add ok button
                    alert.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (actionOK) => {
                            // Any action?
                            if (action != null && field != null) {
                                    action (true, field.Text);
                            }
                    }));

                    // Display the alert
                    controller.PresentViewController (alert, true, null);

                    // Return created controller
                    return alert;
            }
            public static void Alert (List<string> listToAlert, string heading, UIViewController controller)
            {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder ();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listToAlert.Count; i++) {
                            stringBuilder.Append (listToAlert [i]);
                            stringBuilder.Append ("\r\n");
                    }
                    AlertViewController.PresentOKAlert (heading, stringBuilder.ToString (), controller);
            }
            #endregion
            #region Delegates
            public delegate void AlertOKCancelDelegate (bool OK);
            public delegate void AlertTextInputDelegate (bool OK, string text);
            #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the action until the user click in the ok button , you should add it after create the UI alert controller

```
var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create ("Title", "The      message", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    //Ads Action
    okAlertController.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

    // Present Alert
    PresentViewController (okAlertController, true, null);
```

Take a look in the documentation to see more samples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/alerts

Comment: Hey Rccardo. that is a clone of their example.. :)

Comment: Yes, the code that I pasted is the sample that is in the documentation.

Comment: That doc you pointed me to is the source of the problem. you cloned the answer without trying it. What you gave me will not compile. FYI there are 2500 issues against that one doc.

Comment: If you copy the exact code that is in the documentation (the one that is already on this response) you are going to display an alert with a "ok" button.

Comment: You are adding the action for the alert inside on the TouchUpInside event, and you are not adding  okayButton in your view,  so where are you firing TouchUpInside ????

Comment: i think there is assumptions about the context of the call. I fixed and provided screenshot + working code below. I am not calling from a View Context that is why your code would not compile. Thanks for your effort

Comment: The question is about how to add ok button in the alert, with the code that I shared is how works, ...... the way that you need to present the alert is not related with the question.... but already saw your answer ,You are doing how is in the documentation....Its great that you have it working.